# Java: regex pattern that ignores any number that contains a decimal

Tags: java, regex

I have a string 
`match = "234 587.094";`
What I need to find, using regex, is every integer in the string only.
When matched against a pattern, this should only return `234` because `587.094` is not an integer.

Here's the pattern I have so far:

```
Pattern int_p = "(\\d+[^(\\.?\\d+)])";
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, if it should return the "integer" only, shouldn't the output be 234587 ?

Comment: @Sentient07, Technically `587.094` is a `float`.

Comment: @Sentient07 I think he has 2 separate numbers there "234" and "567.094" and he wants to return only those numbers that are integers. So a list of "123, 456, 7.89, 10.3, 6" would return 123, 456, and 6.

Comment: Sorry. That's my issue: I don't want the 'int' if there is any decimal attached. I know it still appears as an integer, but how do you keep from matching a number with decimal, somewhere, inside of it?

Comment: @vulpcod3z What do we know about input? Does it contain only numbers? Can numbers start with `.` like `.23`? Can there be input like `1.2.3.4`? Or maybe it is part of sentence and number can be placed at end of sentence right before period like `I am 23.`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this pattern

```
"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"
```

It matches both integers and decimals, but when you find a decimal you just ignore it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "234 587.094 123 3.4 6";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?").matcher(data);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group(1) == null) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
234
123
6
```

### UPDATE

Or you can strip out all of the decimal numbers with a `replaceAll()` with this pattern

```
"\\d+\\.\\d+"
```

Then you're left with just the integers for which you can use the pattern `\\d+`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "234 587.094 123 3.4 6 99999.9999 876";

    // Remove decimal numbers
    data = data.replaceAll("\\d+\\.\\d+", "");

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(data);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Results:

```
234
123
6
876
```

Comment: This has been the most efficient solution I've tried thus far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First split your String with 1 or more spaces `\s+` and store in array of strings then filter out the

values which does not contains a `"."`. Try this:

```
String str = "234 587.094";
String[] array = str.split("\\s+");

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if(!array[i].contains(".")){
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `contains` method of a `String` takes a `CharSequence`, not a regular expression so there's no need to escape that dot. Further, in Java you'd need a double slash to actually escape it.

Answer (score 1):

In one line, this code extracts the number if one is found, or blank if not:

```
String num = str.replaceAll(".*?(^|[^.\\d])(\\d+)?($|[^.\\d]).*$", "$2");
```

It does this by requiring that the preceding and following chars of the group are neither a dot nor a digit (and covers the edge case of start/end of input).

The added special sauce of returning blank for no match if achieved by adding `?` to the captured group, allowing it to be absent (thus capturing nothing), yet allowing the whole expression to still match the entire input, thus returning nothing.

---

Here's some test code:

```
for (String str : new String[] {"234 587.094", "234",  "xxx", "foo 587.094"})
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*?(^|[^.\\d])(\\d+)?($|[^.\\d]).*$", "$2"));
```

Output:

```
234
234
<blank>
<blank>
```